# Projectile motion given angular projection

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

When a body is projected with a certain angle  from the ground it returns with the same angle and speed with which it was projected. What if the the body was projected from some height, maybe a building. Will it still reach the ground with same speed and angle?

Answer (score 2):

No, because once the particle goes below the level of projection, the speed increases, due to conservation of energy. Also the angle of flight, given by $\tan\phi=\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}$, increases because $\dot{y}$ increases while $\dot{x}$ remains constant.